# Proving that a linear operator is hermitian

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I would like some help with the following problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

Consider $Lu(x) = iu′(x)$ where $u ∈ ML = C^1(R) ∩ L^2(R)$. Show that $⟨Lf,g⟩ = ⟨f,Lg⟩$ for any $f$ and $g$ from $ML$.

Comment: Is your inner product the usual $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\bar{g}dx$? If so, just do integration by parts.

Comment: It is. If you do integration by parts, you still have to take care of the integral of f(x) multiplied by the conjugate of the first derivative of g(x)

Comment: the conjugate of the first derivative of g'(x) is almost $L$. Also notice that $\bar{i}=-i$.

Comment: What do you mean when you write that the conjugate of g'(x) is almost L?

Comment: Write down the integration by parts. You get $-i\int f \bar{g'}dx$ right?

Comment: Correct, in addition to the term if(x) multiplied by the conjugate of g(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is in ML. Then $ff'$ is absolutely integrable because $f$ and $f'$ are square integrable. Thus, the following has finite limits as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$:
$$
              \left.2\int_{0}^{x}ff'dx = f^{2}\right|_{0}^{x}=f(x)^{2}-f(0)^{2}.
$$
The only possible limit for $f(x)^{2}$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ is $0$ because assuming otherwise leads to the contradiction that $f^{2}$ is not absolutely integrable. So,
$$
                   \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0,\;\;\; f \in ML.
$$
If $f, g \in ML$, then $f'g$ and $fg'$ are absolutely integrable because $f,f',g,g'$ are square integrable. Hence, the following exists as $R\rightarrow 0$ and equals $0$:
$$
                  \left.\int_{-R}^{R}(f'g+fg')dx = (fg)\right|_{-R}^{R}
$$
Thus, for all $f,g\in ML$, one has
$$
                      \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'g\,dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fg'\,dx
$$
You can finish be replacing $g$ by $\overline{g}$ and then worrying about 'i'.

Comment: Given's OP's definition that $ML=C^1(R)\cap L^2(R)$, technically, $f'$ is not necessarily in $L^2$ right? Or did you just mean that $f,f'$ are square integrable on a finite region $[0,x]$?

Comment: @AlexR. : Oops. I just assumed that was part of the formulation. It needs to be part of the formulation, and it's the standard way to define an operator on $L^{2}$. Otherwise the inner-product expressions do not make sense. But you're right that he did not assume that to be the case.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Your assumption about f' is correct. I should have been clearer.

Comment: @T.A.E.: I'm having trouble following this proof. Why is it that f'g+fg'=fg?

Comment: @JohnDarson : $\int (f'g+fg')dx = fg+C$ or $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDarson : You're welcome.