# Show that <Lu,u> is greater than or equal to zero

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I would like some help with the following problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

Let $$Lu(x) = −u''(x)$$ where $u \in ML = C^2(\mathbb{R}) ∩ L_2(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $\langle Lu, u \rangle \ge 0$ for all $u \in ML$.

I realize that the problem boils down to showing that the integral from negative infinity to infinity of $u'(x)$ multiple by its complex conjugate must be greater than or equal to zero, but I am unsure how to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that $u'' \in L^{2}$ (which seems to be missing,) it follows that
$u' \in L^{2}$. To see why, note that $u''u$ is absolutely integrable because $u'',u$ are square integrable. That gives the absolutely integrability of $u''u=(u'u)'-u'^{2}$. So the following remains uniformly bounded for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
                \left.\int_{0}^{x}u''udx = u'u\right|_{0}^{x}-\int_{0}^{x}u'^{2}dx.
$$
Thus $\int_{0}^{\infty}u'^{2}dx =\infty$ iff $\lim_{x\rightarrow}u'u = \infty$, but the latter case trivially implies
$$
    \frac{1}{2}(u^{2})'=u'u \ge M > 0
$$
for all large $x$. That is, there exists $R > 0$ such that $(u^{2})' \ge M/2$ for all $x \ge R$, which leads to $u^{2}(x) \ge u^{2}(R)+Mx/2$, thereby contradicting the fact that $u \in L^{2}$. So $\int_{0}^{\infty}u'^{2}dx < \infty$. Similarly, $\int_{-\infty}^{0}u'^{2}dx < \infty$, which gives $u,u',u'' \in L^{2}$.

Now I'm going to appeal to another problem of yours: [Proving that a linear operator is hermitian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142502/proving-that-a-linear-operator-is-hermitian) . Knowing that $f=u',f'=u''$ are in $L^{2}$ and that $g=u,g'=u'$ are in $L^{2}$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
     -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'gdx & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fg'dx \\
     -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u''udx & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u'u'dx \ge 0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What happened to the complex conjugates? There must be something I am not understanding about why the above also holds in the case of u'(x) multiple by its complex conjugate.

Comment: @JohnDarson : You didn't specify complex; so I worked with real. In the first paragraph, you may assume $u$ is real without loss of generality because $u$ is in the stated function classes iff the real and imaginary parts of $u$ are in those classes. In the second paragraph, let $g=\overline{u}$ instead of $g=u$.

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ has compact support, then, integrating by parts you have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} u(x) \cdot (-u''(x)) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u'(x) \cdot u'(x) dx \geq 0$$

Since functions with compact support are dense in $L^2 \cap C^2$, the inequality holds everywhere.

Comment: Can you prove the last sentence, or at least direct me to a proof?

Comment: I found this on the Internet http://texas.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/f06/m5340_f06/mollifiers_approx.pdf . This theorem is very important in the study of functional analysis: for example it allows you to define weak derivatives and Sobolev spaces, and in general it allows you to study a lot of continuous operators only on the space of smooth functions with compact support.